# Manually acknowledge Kafka Event A consuming after producing event B

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a case where I have to consume event A and do some processing, then  produce the event B. So my problem is what would happen is the processing crashed and the application couldn't produce B while it consumed already A. My approach is to acknowledge after successfully publishing B, am I correct or should implement another solution for this case?

```
@KafkaListener(
        id = TOPIC_ID,
        topics = TOPIC_ID,
        groupId = GROUP_ID,
        containerFactory = LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY
)
public void listen(List<Message<A>> messages, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {

    try {
        final AEvent aEvent = messages.stream()
                .filter(message -> null != message.getPayload())
                .map(Message::getPayload)
                .findFirst()
                .get();

        processDao.doSomeProcessing() // returns a Mono<Example> by calling an externe API
                .subscribe(
                        response -> {
                            ProducerRecord<String, BEvent> BEventRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC_ID, null, BEvent);

                            ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, BEvent>> future = kafkaProducerTemplate.send(buildBEvent());
                            future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, BEvent>>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, BEvent> BEventSendResult) {
                                    //TODO: do when event published successfully
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Throwable exception) {
                                    exception.printStackTrace();
                                    throw new ExampleException();
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        error -> {
                            error.printStackTrace();
                            throw new ExampleException();
                        }
                );
        acknowledgment.acknowledge(); // ??
    } catch (ExampleException) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't manage kafka "acknowledgments" when using async code such as reactor.

Kafka does not manage discrete acks for each topic/partition, just the last committed offset for the partition.

If you process two records asynchronously, you will have a race as to which offset will be committed first.

You need to perform the sends on the listener container thread to maintain proper ordering.

Comment: How can I use the listen thread for that in this case?
Could you please give me a hint of how  should I refactor this code to have a proper ordering?
Thanks

Comment: I don't now reactor very well, but I think you need to call `block()` on the `Mono<?>` instead of `subscribe()` and use the result to send the message. You can then call acknowledge when the future completes, or throw an exception and configure a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` so that the record will be redelivered. You really don't need to use manual acks though, `AckMode.BATCH` (default) will cause the container to commit the offsets when the listener exits normally.

Comment: If you want to process the list in parallel; you will need more sophistication - retain your subscriber and use some kind of latch to hold up the listener thread until all the processing is complete. e.g. `new CountDownLatch(messages.size())` and count down the latch with each completion so the listener thread will be released when they are all done.

Comment: If I understand well,by using the error handler `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler ` (like [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-for-apache-kafka-deep-dive-part-1-error-han)), my application is going to listen again to the same message until the process is finished normally, so no need to implement a manual aknowledge, right?

Comment: Correct - but bear in mind that with a Batch listener; the `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler` has no way to know which record in the batch failed so it can never recover and records will be redelivered indefinitely. This is OK for transient errors but, typically, with a batch listener, error handling/recovery has to be done in the listener itself. You can still use a `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler` but you will need some logic in the listener to give up if the same record keeps failing over and over again.

Comment: Thanks Gary, your answer is very helpful

Comment: I am currently exploring akka framework to solve similar problem as Hadi's , Since Akka has cyclic feedback a mechanism to hold reference to triggerring actor and reply to same actor . But my dataset is not very huge.